# How to ignore already compressed files and remove original raw file

Tags: batch, compression, zip, 7-zip

I have tried the following code with 7zip but once I run the batch script it keeps compressing the already compressed file inside the folder. Is there a way to ignore .zip file type and delete the original file after it has been compressed? Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Code:

```
FOR %%i IN ("C:\filepath....\*HAEC040.D*") DO "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a  -mx "%%~i.zip" "%%i"
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's all in the 7Zip helpfile, under Command Line version, or from the command line help (7z -h):

```
-ax[r[-|0]]{@listfile|!wildcard} : eXclude archives
-sdel : delete files after compression
-x[r[-|0]]{@listfile|!wildcard} : eXclude filenames

-mx[N] : set compression level: -mx1 (fastest) ... -mx9 (ultra)
```

So your zip command would look something like this (by the way, you left off the number for your compression level on the `mx` flag:

```
7z.exe a "%%~i.zip" "%%i" -mx1 -sdel -xr!*.zip
```

Testing is left as an exercise for the user. Be careful with that delete flag! Setup a specific folder for testing with dummy data before using on actual data you care about.